# Install package only for one project

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Let's say I have this file hierarchy:

packages/project1 
packages/project2

and the workspace is packages/*

How do I install an npm package only for project1 and not for project2 (without using just "npm install" inside the packages/project1 directory because I need the yarn lock file to include the dependency)?

Does yarn support this functionality? Couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: `yarn add` works like `npm i` if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yarn add <package...> [--dev/-D]
```

Using `--dev` or `-D` will install one or more packages in your devDependencies. See [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)